# Cant find an existing Zip-Code

Tags: google-maps

I have a valid zip code for germany that I cant find via google maps

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=postcode:70159,de&sensor=false

The call should return a valid german location (Stuttgart), but it returns New Orleans.

The Format of the call is right: I can choose between german and american locations by calling

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=postcode:22301,de&sensor=false

for Germany or

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=postcode:22301,us&sensor=false

for USA

Is this a common issue and can I do something about it?

I confirmed that the ZIP code is ok

http://www.plz-postleitzahl.com/de/plzinfo.cfm?parm=70159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker found the answer:

Some Zip codes are associated with corporations. These Zip codes dont have a geolocation.